# count specific text in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Right now, I have a spreadsheet with keys and names.For each key, I would like to count how many of similar names there are. I tried using a pivot table by putting keys+names under the "Row labels" and names under the "Values" tab. But this gave me a count of 1 for each name since they are all different. I would like a count of all the common names by maybe using a COUNTIF to search for a specific text? Not sure what the best way is since I have over 10,000 keys and each key has like 10-20 different names, all different but some contain similar text.

What I have now:

```
**key1:**          yahoo test1 
**key1:**          google test 
**key1:**          microsoft test 
**key1:**          test microsoft test
**Key1:**          yahoo test   




**key2:**          mozilla test1 
**key2:**          amazon test 
**key2:**          microsoft test 
**key2:**          amazon testing
**Key2:**          mozilla test4
```

What I expect to get:

```
key1: yahoo: 2
      google: 1
      microsoft: 2

key2: mozilla: 2
      amazon: 2
      microsoft:1
```

Comment: you need to have a list with the keys you want to check, like "yahoo" , "google", " microsoft", etc... and then check all values that match "* yahoo *".

Comment: added to what @ShaiRado says, you could also consider using wild cards : " *oogl* " or " *aho* " etc to reduce the list length.

Comment: So I would make a list of all the words I want to look for, and then do what? what function would I write to compare? and I want the count sepertly for each key, not the whole spreadsheet.